# Is there a way to have Domino show file DB path instead of replica ID for DocLinks on the web?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We are converting an application that was built in R6 to xpages.  In this application, the content was created through the Notes client and viewed on the web.  There are a lot of doc links in the documents.  Some of the documents have readers fields and that's where theproblem arises.

When looking at a page that contains links to "secured" documents, the URL is something like:

http://servername/dbpath/db.nsf/whaterverdoclinkhere

The links that this page contains all show a URL that looks like this:

http://servername/__REPLICAID/ViewUNID/DocUNID

The problem that we have is that this seems to be considered different DBs from a securitypoint of view and even though the user is logged in when accessing the first page, he gets the login page when he clicks on a link that uses the replica ID of the database instead of its path.

Is there a way to force Domino to use the database path all the time in URLs built with doc links, not the URL with the replica ID?

Comment: Do you have session based authentication vor basic auth. enabled? I assume that you shoud more focus ob the auth. Issue than trying to modify he links.

Comment: Even without session authentiction, I think there is a way to deal with it. It's been a long time, so I would have to study up on the details, but it has to do with the concept of the "realm" of the page that you were in when you authenticate. By default, the realm is one level above the page you are accessing (so usually the view in simple apps), but you can control this via config docs. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_WEB_SITE_AUTHENTICATION_REALM_STEPS.html

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to the placement of the doclinks?

Comment: Patrick, these links were created in the previous version of the application, where all the content creation was done through the Notes client, and users were shown how to create doc links